# Pinia useStore returns any

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pinia

I'm using Pinia with Vue3 and TypeScript. Using the many different ways of typing the store, I have been unable to get the store to be typed as anything other than `any`.

Here's the implementation:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import type { DataT } from "@/types";

interface DataStore {
  data: DataT[];
}

export const useDataStore = defineStore("dataStore", {
  state: (): DataStore => ({
    data: [] as DataT[],
  }),
});
```

Anywhere this store is imported in a component, the return type of `useDataStore()` is `any`, which is not typesafe. How can I get type-safety from my store?

All vue components are using `<script lang="ts" setup>` and are successfully using other TS types elsewhere.

Here's an example of how it's being imported:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
// some other imports
import { useDataStore } from "../../store/data";

const dataStore = useDataStore();
// other code follows
</script>
```

Comment: There were similar questions. This seems to be a bug with IDE. It's Jetbrains, isn't it?

Comment: VSCode. I'm especially confused because I have another repo with typing working but can't find any differences between the two.

Comment: TS version in use could be a difference